# Guardar los valores de cada iteración de un ciclo while en una matriz en R Studio

Tags: r, matrices, while

estoy trabajando con métodos para encontrar raíces de una función, tengo el siguiente código en R Studio y corre a la perfección:

```js
#### Método de bisección
fun<-function(x){
  return(z<-(x^3+4*(x^2)-10)) #Función a la que se le aplicará el método
}

met_biseccion<-function(a,b,itera,tol){ #Definimos el método de bisección 
  funa<-fun(a) #Función evaluada en a
  funb<-fun(b) #Función evaluada en b
  if(funa*funb>0){ #Validamos si se puede aplicar el método
    print("EL MÉTODO NO SE PUEDE APLICAR")
  }else{
    contador<-0 
    while(contador<=itera){ #El proceso seguirá hasta el número de iteraciones que haya ingresado el usuario
      c<-(a+b)/2 #Obtenemos el punto medio entre a y b
      func<-fun(c) #Función evaluada en c
      if(abs(func-0)>tol){ #Buscamos que func sea lo más cercano a 0, para así decir que c es nuestra raíz
        if(func*funa<0){ #Validamos si son de signos distintos
          b<-c
          funb<-func
        }else{
          a<-c
          funa<-func
        }
        contador<-contador+1
        #Configuramos la matriz para que vaya haciendo la tabla de comparación
      } else{
        break()
      }
    }
  }
  return(x<-c(c, func,contador))
}

(a<-met_biseccion(-5,2,20,.001)) #Aplicamos el método, escribimos el intervalo, las iteraciones y la tolerancia
```

El problema es que sólo me muestra los valores de la última iteración y necesito todos los valores guardados en una matriz, me podrían ayudar, de antemano, muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida Dinn09 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberías hacer con cada iteración es ir guardando los valores. Lo más cómodo y performante es hacerlo en un lista, y al salir tranformar la misma en una matriz. Algo así:

```
met_biseccion<-function(a,b,itera,tol){ #Definimos el método de bisección 
  funa<-fun(a) #Función evaluada en a
  funb<-fun(b) #Función evaluada en b
  if(funa*funb>0){ #Validamos si se puede aplicar el método
    stop("EL MÉTODO NO SE PUEDE APLICAR")
  }else{
    contador<-0 
    l <- list()
    while(contador<=itera){ #El proceso seguirá hasta el número de iteraciones que haya ingresado el usuario
      c<-(a+b)/2 #Obtenemos el punto medio entre a y b
      func<-fun(c) #Función evaluada en c
      if(abs(func-0)>tol){ #Buscamos que func sea lo más cercano a 0, para así decir que c es nuestra raíz
        if(func*funa<0){ #Validamos si son de signos distintos
          b<-c
          funb<-func
        }else{
          a<-c
          funa<-func
        }
        contador<-contador+1
        #Configuramos la matriz para que vaya haciendo la tabla de comparación
        l[[contador]] <- cbind(c, func, contador)
      } else{
        break()
      }
    }
  }

  return(do.call(rbind, l)
}
```

Detalle:

- Antes del ciclo creamos una lista vacía: `l <- list()`
- en cada iteración, agregamos los datos en esta lista: `l[[contador]] <- cbind(c, func, contador)`
- Al salir retornamos la lista convertida en una matriz: `return(do.call(rbind, l)`
- Adicionalmente, aunque no hace al caso, modifique tu `print` del mensaje de error por un `stop()`, que resulta más lógico como forma de manejar un error en una función.
- Comentario extra, cuidado con los nombres de variable, puntualmente hablo de `c` que es además una función fundamental de `R`, si bien no hay conflicto en este caso, puede provocar confusión.

Ejemplo:

```
> met_biseccion(-5,2,20,.001)

              c         func contador
 [1,] -1.500000 -4.375000000        1
 [2,]  0.250000 -9.734375000        2
 [3,]  1.125000 -3.513671875        3
 [4,]  1.562500  3.580322266        4
 [5,]  1.343750 -0.350982666        5
 [6,]  1.453125  1.514667511        6
 [7,]  1.398438  0.557332516        7
 [8,]  1.371094  0.097108781        8
 [9,]  1.357422 -0.128445812        9
[10,]  1.364258 -0.016046691       10
[11,]  1.367676  0.040436382       11
[12,]  1.365967  0.012171194       12
[13,]  1.365112 -0.001943659       13
[14,]  1.365540  0.005112290       14
[15,]  1.365326  0.001583946       15
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Lo había intentado, pero sólo me aparecían los datos de la primera iteración, ya vi en dónde tuve el error, nuevamente, gracias!